# OpenRasta - Providing Filter, Sorting and Paging for List Resources

Tags: sorting, filtering, paging, openrasta, restful-url

We are creating a REST API using OpenRasta and apart from regular GET, POST, PUT and DELETE on all resources, we are also providing GET on resources with plural names. So a consumer of the API can GET, POST, PUT and DELETE on `User` and also perform GET on `Users` which will return `List<Users>`. Now we want the clients to be able to filter and sort it by it's properties and allow to support paging for showing data in paged tabular formats.

Although, I looked at [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) home page and looks like it can be useful but after looking at blog posts and Getting Started page, I couldn't understand how I can use it to solve my problem in OpenRasta.

Or is there anything else simpler that I can do?

Answer (score 2):

OR doesn't support stuff like OData for that functionality, mainly because it leads to very unrestful systems.

If /users is "the list of users", then it is a different resource than /users/1 (the first page of users) or /users/byName/1 (the first page of users ordered by name).

You can of course implement all this easily by registering a URI that has query parameters, as those are optional

```
.AtUri("/users?page={page}&filter={filter}
```

And your handler can look like

```
public List<User> Get(int page = 0, string filter = null) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi seb, how does it leads to an unrestful system , can you give an example? thanks. Also, allowing client to specify "fields" they would like to get back for a given resource, does that consider bad?

Comment: It leads to very static URI definitions, bloated media types and low fidelity to what is supposed to be achieved. I've highlighted those issues at NDC years ago, the video is available somewhere. For the list of fields a user would like for a specific resource means that it is a different resource, it can lead to very poor practices or make your URI scheme very ineffective for caching and intermediaries. Like everything else, it's a balance between RPC and ReST for your system, so there are no strict answers bar infringing the ReST constraints or not.